# WebSockets in WebGL with Unity

Tags: spring, unity-game-engine, websocket, vaadin, webgl

I failed to find a solution for this and hope the community can help me out.

My app:

- Vaadin 24 Frontend
- Spring Boot / Spring Security Backend
- IFrame with Unity WebGL app.
- NativeWebSockets library (https://github.com/endel/NativeWebSocket/)

What I am trying to achive:
Run a webgl unity app (developed in c#) in an IFrame in my app and connect to my spring boot backend via websockets.

Testing and error:
I have a fully working example prototype at localhost!
When I deploy it live, I get a 403 Forbidden.

I further tested writing a simple websocket client and server app and deployed them on my server. This showed me I dont have a NGINX problem. NGINX seems to work and redirects from port 80 to 8080. The java websocket example client even could connect via SSL, so even the certificate works fine. So my websocket server api works, the cert works, and connecting via java from remote works. Also connecting via browser and using the Iframe works, BUT ONLY local.

I failed to get this running and would apreciate tips. I really tried a lot. But I am not good at spring boot security. My java class is:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    public static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/";

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/**")).permitAll();
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, LOGOUT_URL);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for reading this and for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem myself.The remote ip wasnt forwarded, so the client script tried to connect to localhost. x-forwarded-for header must be set in nginx configuration and via a spring bean.

NGINX:

```
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Spring:

```
@Configuration
public class ForwardedForConfiguration {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    logger.info("Forwarded-for header filter loaded.");
    FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    bean.setFilter(new ForwardedHeaderFilter());
    return bean;
}
```

}